# Error upload image from url in php (&wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, url, plugins, download

I develop a plugin for wordpress which download image from URL for create a post(article).

For the most part, the image is download and article posted but sometime, for curious reason, the image is not download.

Specifically, a file corrupted is download without declared errors. (like download is cutted pending process)

Concrete example : 
http://static.lexpress.fr/medias_10713/w_1624,h_1219,c_crop,x_345,y_113/w_605,h_350,c_fill,g_north/v1450339163/marine-le-pen-france-s-national-front-political-party-head-checks-notes-on-her-mobile-phone-after-leaving-her-polling-station-during-the-european-parliament-election-in-henin-beaumont_5485394.jpg

Look this link. You can see this image with your browser without problem.
But my plugin cannt download this file. You can test that with this site :
[img uploader](http://imgur.com/)
Try to upload this image with this site and you will have a error. But why ?!? The image can be open in browser! I become crazy, do you have idea please ? I don't know what can i search on web for find a solution..

Thanks you

Comment: Displaying image through HTTP and downloading it through an other server are two different things. You can allow one but block the other. I suspect l'express website to block download of their pictures. PS: couldn't find any better image as example? :-(

Comment: Hi, thanks you for you response. And sorry for my english bad.
Yes, for blocking website (express), i think the same thing but i must found a hack for pass this problem. Do you know something about blocking image url (just keyword for search on google) ?

This article is agaist this politic people (this article said, "Marine Lepen" have send Daesh video barbar and she candamned for 4years jails :) )

Thanks you vard

Comment: Just answered to you, seems CURL works great for this. I know I'm french so I'm aware of this, it's just that I'm tired to see his face everywere :-) But I'm a little off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using curl I didn't have any issue to download this image:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://static.lexpress.fr/medias_10713/w_1624,h_1219,c_crop,x_345,y_113/w_605,h_350,c_fill,g_north/v1450339163/marine-le-pen-france-s-national-front-political-party-head-checks-notes-on-her-mobile-phone-after-leaving-her-polling-station-during-the-european-parliament-election-in-henin-beaumont_5485394.jpg');
$fp = fopen('./test.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

I guess you were using `file_get_contents` instead. Downloading the picture binary through curl seems to bypass the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much Vard, it's working perfeclty!

But i give informations for other peoples : Some server don't active CURL, so you must check it before use this hack.

Code for check that :

```
  if (!is_callable('curl_init')) {
        error_log("Curl no exist, request impossible..", 3, plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)."../logs/error.log");
        header("HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented");
        exit("Curl request impossible for wordpress server");
    }
enter code here
```

*Grand Merci Vard (sorry i don't have enought point for a positive vote about your response but you are so kind)*